# Flutter Web Unexpected Null Value

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDX2d.jpg) I get Unexpected Null value error when switching from Home page to Vehicle Add page. I couldn't understand what caused this.

I tried to run it in debug mode, but it was very confusing in debug mode, I couldn't understand it.

home.dart page

```
import 'package:Car_Price_App/Pages/category_add.dart';
import 'package:Car_Price_App/Pages/vehicle_add.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../services/auth_service.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});


  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final email = user?.email;

    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text("Sıfır Araçlar ${email?.toUpperCase()}")),
        leading: const Icon(Icons.car_rental),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> CategoryAdd(gelenEmail: email.toString(),)));
            print("giden $email");
          }, icon: const Icon(Icons.category)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> VehicleAdd()));
          }, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.update)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Giriş Yapıldı $email"),
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              AuthService().signOut();
            }, child: const Text("Çıkış Yap",),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

vehicle_add.dart  page

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:currency_text_input_formatter/currency_text_input_formatter.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../models/trade_mark_model.dart';
import '../models/type_of_vehicle_model.dart';
import '../models/vehicle_body_type_model.dart';
import '../models/vehicle_model.dart';
import '../models/vehicle_year_model.dart';

class VehicleAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  const VehicleAdd({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VehicleAdd> createState() => _VehicleAddState();
}

class _VehicleAddState extends State<VehicleAdd> {
  GlobalKey? aracEkleKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  TextEditingController vehicleProperties = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController vehiclePrice = TextEditingController();
  String? vasitaTipi = "";
  String? kasaTipi = "";
  String? marka = "";
  String? model = "";
  String? yil = "";

  PlatformFile? pickedFile;
  UploadTask? uploadTask;

  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result == null) return;
    setState(() {
      pickedFile = result.files.first;
    });
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    final path = 'aracResimleri/${pickedFile?.name}';
    final file = File(pickedFile!.path!);

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    setState(() {
      uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);
    });

    final snapshot = await uploadTask?.whenComplete(() {});
    final urlDownload = await snapshot?.ref.getDownloadURL();
    print('Download Link : $urlDownload');
    setState(() {
      uploadTask = null;
    });
  }

  Stream<List<TypeOfVehicleModel>> readVehicleType() => db.collection("Vasıtalar").snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => TypeOfVehicleModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  Stream<List<VehicleBodyTypeModel>> readBodyType() => db.collection("KasaTipleri").snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => VehicleBodyTypeModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  Stream<List<TradeMarkModel>> readTradeMark() => db.collection("Markalar").snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => TradeMarkModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  Stream<List<VehicleModel>> readVehicleModel() => db.collection("Modeller").snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => VehicleModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  Stream<List<VehicleYearModel>> readVehicleYear() => db.collection("Yıllar").snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => VehicleYearModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());

  late int _key;
  _collapse() {
    int? newKey;
    do {
      _key = Random().nextInt(10000);
    } while (newKey == _key);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _collapse();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenInfo = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final double screenWidth = screenInfo.size.width;
    final double screenHeight = screenInfo.size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Araç Ekle"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Form(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              key: aracEkleKey,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: screenWidth / 2,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder<List<TypeOfVehicleModel>>(
                      future: readVehicleType().first,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final typeOfVehicle = snapshot.data!;
                          return ExpansionTile(
                            key: Key(_key.toString()),
                            initiallyExpanded: false,
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.merge_type),
                            title: const Text("Vasıta Seçiniz"),
                            children: typeOfVehicle.map(buildTov).toList(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ), // Vasıta Tipi
                    Text("$vasitaTipi"),
                    Text("$kasaTipi"),
                    Text("$marka"),
                    Text("$model"),
                    Text("$yil"),
                    FutureBuilder<List<VehicleBodyTypeModel>>(
                      future: readBodyType().first,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final bodyType = snapshot.data!;
                          return ExpansionTile(
                            key: Key(_key.toString()),
                            initiallyExpanded: false,
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.type_specimen),
                            title: const Text("Kasa Tipi Seçiniz"),
                            children: bodyType.map(buildBodyType).toList(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ), // Kasatipi
                    FutureBuilder<List<TradeMarkModel>>(
                      future: readTradeMark().first,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final tradeMarka = snapshot.data!;
                          return ExpansionTile(
                            key: Key(_key.toString()),
                            initiallyExpanded: false,
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.branding_watermark),
                            title: const Text("Marka Seçiniz"),
                            children: tradeMarka.map(buildTradeMark).toList(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ), //Markalar
                    FutureBuilder<List<VehicleModel>>(
                      future: readVehicleModel().first,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final model = snapshot.data!;
                          return ExpansionTile(
                            key: Key(_key.toString()),
                            initiallyExpanded: false,
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.time_to_leave),
                            title: const Text("Model Seçiniz"),
                            children: model.map(buildModel).toList(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ), //Modeller
                    FutureBuilder<List<VehicleYearModel>>(
                      future: readVehicleYear().first,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final year = snapshot.data!;
                          return ExpansionTile(
                            key: Key(_key.toString()),
                            initiallyExpanded: false,
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                            title: const Text(
                              "Yıl Seçiniz",
                            ),
                            children: year.map(buildYear).toList(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ), //Yıllar
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: vehicleProperties,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Araç Özellikleri Giriniz",
                          suffixText: "Araç Özellikleri Giriniz",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        minLines: 1,
                        maxLines: screenHeight.toInt(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          // for below version 2 use this
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                            r'\d',
                          )),
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          CurrencyTextInputFormatter(
                            symbol: '₺',
                            name: "TL",
                          )
                        ],
                        controller: vehiclePrice,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Araç Fiyat Giriniz",
                          suffixText: "Araç Fiyat Giriniz",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        minLines: 1,
                        maxLines: screenHeight.toInt(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Image.file(
                        File(pickedFile!.path!),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
                      onPressed: () {
                        selectFile();
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text("Araç Resmi Seç"),
                                content: Text(pickedFile!.name),
                                actions: [
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        uploadFile();
                                      },
                                      child: const Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        "Galeri'den Seç",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                                      ))),
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      },
                      label: const Text("Araç Resimi Ekle"),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder<TaskSnapshot>(
                      stream: uploadTask!.snapshotEvents,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final data = snapshot.data!;
                          double progress = data.bytesTransferred / data.totalBytes;
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            child: Stack(
                              fit: StackFit.expand,
                              children: [
                                LinearProgressIndicator(
                                  value: progress,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${(100 * progress).roundToDouble()} %',
                                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      // Fab Buton visible olacak doldurulması geren herşey dolduğunda gözükecek
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          // bool kontrolSonucu = aracEkleKey.currentState!.validate();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTov(TypeOfVehicleModel typeOfVehicleModel) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _collapse();
            vasitaTipi = typeOfVehicleModel.typeOfVehicle;
          });

          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("$vasitaTipi");
          }
        },
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.stars_outlined,
          size: 10,
        ),
        title: Text(typeOfVehicleModel.typeOfVehicle.toString()),
      ); //Araç vasıta tipi

  Widget buildBodyType(VehicleBodyTypeModel vehicleBodyTypeModel) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _collapse();
            kasaTipi = vehicleBodyTypeModel.vehicleBodyType;
          });
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(vehicleBodyTypeModel.vehicleBodyType);
          }
        },
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.stars_outlined,
          size: 10,
        ),
        title: Text(vehicleBodyTypeModel.vehicleBodyType.toString()),
      ); // Araç kasa tipi

  Widget buildTradeMark(TradeMarkModel tradeMarkModel) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _collapse();
            marka = tradeMarkModel.tradeMarkName;
          });
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(tradeMarkModel.tradeMarkName);
          }
        },
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.stars_outlined,
          size: 10,
        ),
        title: Text(tradeMarkModel.tradeMarkName.toString()),
      ); // Araç MArka

  Widget buildModel(VehicleModel vehicleModel) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _collapse();
            model = vehicleModel.modelName;
          });
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(vehicleModel.modelName);
          }
        },
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.stars_outlined,
          size: 10,
        ),
        title: Text(vehicleModel.modelName.toString()),
      ); // Araç Modeli

  Widget buildYear(VehicleYearModel vehicleYearModel) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _collapse();
            yil = vehicleYearModel.year;
          });
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(vehicleYearModel.year);
          }
        },
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.stars_outlined,
          size: 10,
        ),
        title: Text(vehicleYearModel.year.toString()),
      ); // Araç Yılı

  Widget buildProgress() => StreamBuilder<TaskSnapshot>(
        stream: uploadTask?.snapshotEvents,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data!;
            double progress = data.bytesTransferred / data.totalBytes;
            return SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: progress,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${(100 * progress).roundToDouble()} %',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            );
          }
        },
      );
}
```

I don't know which variable is causing the problem. I'm inexperienced in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says on which line the error is. See

[image]

That means it's on line 297. If I'm not mistaken that is the line:

```
child: Image.file(File(pickedFile!.path!),
```

So `pickedFile` is `null`

Comment: how can i fix this